# Uncaught ReferenceError: myClass is not defined

Tags: javascript

Error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Jtable is not defined

I'm trying to use my custom class called `Jtable`, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, someone can help me?

This is my file1 code:

```
(function() {
  var Jtable;

  Jtable = (function() {
    function Jtable(cols) {
      this.cols = cols;
    }

    Jtable.prototype.create_header = function() {
      var table, tr;
      tr = create_header_row();
      return table = $('<table>').append(tr);
    };

    Jtable.prototype.create_header_row = function() {
      var tr;
      tr = $('<tr>');
      $.each(this.cols, function(key, value) {
        var th;
        th = $('<th>').append(value);
        return tr.append(th);
      });
      return tr;
    };

    return Jtable;

  })();

}).call(this);
```

This is my file2 code:

```
$(function() {
  var cols = ['col-1', 'col-2', 'col-3'];
  var table = new Jtable(cols);
});
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Here are my scripts:

```
<!-- scripts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="file1.js"></script>
<script src="file2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your `JTable` is described is not available in this context because it is described in the IIFE.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
<script src="path/to/your/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/your/jquery.ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put `var JTable` inside the function. If you want it global you have to move that line above the immediately invoked function